# Django formset is_valid fails Cannot assign "u'username'": "contact" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django inline formset that populates a bunch of forms. One of the field is a contact entry which would a be user name. User can select the user name and data is sent in Post call.
Problem is the formset.is_valid call fails because of the error.

I specifically converted the contact value in request object to specified user object but Django somehow later again converts it a unicode string and i get the error.
I could see that some internal to_python() call seems to convert the user object value to unicode.
Not sure whats happening here.

Model:

```py
class ATest(models.Model):
  contact = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='test_contact', null=True, blank=True)
```

View (Post Call):

```py
  request.POST['atest-0-contact'] = GetOrCreateUserMixin.get_or_create_user(request.POST['atest-0-contact'])
  ctx['formset_test'] \
                            = formset_test \
                            = TestAFormSet(
                                request.POST,
                                instance = test
                            )
                        is_valid = formset_test.is_valid()
```

Form:

```py
class ATestForm(forms.ModelForm, GetOrCreateUserMixin):
    contact = forms.CharField(
        label='Contact',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'autocomplete': 'off',
            'class': 'js-widget-user-typeahead',
            'style': 'width: 95%'
        }),
        # help_text='Begin typing user name',
        required=False
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.ATest
        fields = (
            'contact',
        )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.conflict = {}
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
            super(ATestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.original = {}
            self.fk_display_fields = (
                # contact,

            )


            if contact in self.fields:
                self.fields['contact'].help_text = ''
                self.fields['contact'].label = ''


        def clean_contact(self):
            if not self.cleaned_data['contact']:
                return None
            return self.get_or_create_user(self.cleaned_data['contact'])



TestAFormSet = inlineformset_factory(models.Test, models.ATest, form=ATestForm, formset=BaseAutomationFormSet, extra=0, help_texts=None, labels=None, can_delete=True)
```

Comment: Should the user just select a username from a list or do you specifically intend the user to be able to create a new user by typing a username?

Comment: Also your code has syntax errors (`if contact in self.fields:...` can't work as `contact` isn't defined, do you mean `"contact"`?)

Comment: I don't know what you are doing with that `request.POST['atest-0-contact']...` line but that is certainly not something you should be doing.

Comment: Well the username user types and selects one from possible choices. Yes it should be "contact". This is simplified code - i missed it during copy. request.POST['atest-0-contact'] code directly updates the values in the request. I know it may not be the right way.